# When the militaryHour variable is set to 0, why does the system print 0 and not the hour (variable) I set it which is 12?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to build a program which converts military hours to am or pm time.

I expected the output of 0 to be 12 am, but the actual output is 0 am.

```js
const militaryHour = 0;
    
var hour = 0;
var amOrPm = "am";
    
if (militaryHour < 12) {
    hour = militaryHour;
    console.log(hour + " " + amOrPm);
} else if (militaryHour == 12) {
    amOrPm = "pm";
    hour = 12;
    console.log(hour + " " + amOrPm);
} else if (militaryHour < 24) {
    amOrPm = "pm";
    hour = militaryHour - 12;
    console.log(hour + " " + amOrPm);
} else if (militaryHour == 24){
    hour = 12;
    console.log(hour + " " + amOrPm);
} else {
    hour = 12;
    console.log(hour + " " + amOrPm);
}
```

Comment: 0 is less than 12 - I'd have `if (militaryHour  == 24 || militaryHour == 0){` as the FIRST condition, then `else if (militaryHour == 12)` then the others

Comment: The code is straightforward, just read it through... your first if check is `if (militaryHour < 12)`, that is true because `militaryHour` is currently `0`. So `hour` gets a value of `0` and `0 am` gets logged.

Comment: Note that zero hundred hours and 24 hundred hours are not the same thing.  It's  acceptable to use either, although on 24 hundred hours on one day is technically 0 hundred hours of the next day.  2400 hours is used to denote the end of a day.

Comment: I'd also have `var hour = (militaryHour + 11) % 12 + 1; amOrPm = militaryHour < 12 ? 'am' : 'pm'` - then have no need for any if/else

Comment: @JaromandaX doesn't work.  Gives "12 pm" for military hour = 24, see above

Comment: `militaryHour % 24 < 12` ... so `var hour = (militaryHour + 11) % 12 + 1; amOrPm = militaryHour % 24 < 12 ? 'am' : 'pm'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All the code you need

```
const militaryHour = 0,
    hour = (militaryHour + 11) % 12 + 1,
    amOrPm = militaryHour % 24 < 12 ? 'am' : 'pm';
```

No if/else required

Answer (score 0):

Let's follow your logic

```
const militaryHour = 0; 


if (militaryHour < 12)
```

Ok definitely goes into this if statement because 0<12

```
hour = militaryHour;
console.log(hour + " " + amOrPm);
```

Then log whatever militaryHour is, which is 0. This is why your code is printing "0 am"

12am is actually an edge case. You just need to add one more condition

```
if (militaryHour==0) {
    hour = 12;
    console.log(hour+" "+amOrPm)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your code, the first branch, `if (militaryHour < 12) {...}` is true, so we have:

```
const militaryHour = 0;
var hour = 0;
var amOrPm = "am";
hour = militaryHour;
console.log(hour + " " + amOrPm);
```

It's pretty clear that we're going to get 0 from this.

Here's a solution: take the 24-hour time mod 12. If we wind up with 0, make it 12. Either way, append A.M./P.M. depending on which half of the day the time falls into. All of this eliminates the error-prone large conditional blocks.

```js
const militaryToNormal = hour => 
  (hour % 12 || 12) + (hour % 24 < 12 ? "am" : "pm")
;

for (let i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
  console.log(i, "=>", militaryToNormal(i));
}
```

If you can, prefer [moment.js](https://momentjs.com/).